# Creating Azure Bot Service using ARM template

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-bot-service

I have tried creating with the Azure Bot Service and using the default ARM template generated in Azure, but it is just creating the resource.

Can I create an ARM template which will also configure Azure Bot Service with the following?

1. Language to be used for development (C# or NodeJS).
2. Associate the Microsoft App ID and App Password.
3. Template to be used, such as Basic, Dialog, LUIS or Proactive bot.
4. LUIS Integration.

It would help to create a new environment in Azure easily through templates.

Also I can use the template in DevOps VSTS release step, so that I can automate the deployment process.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking.  Are you following the instructions here:  https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bots/build/first-bot/#navtitle

Comment: Hi Lars, I don't want to create and configure it manually in Azure Portal, instead want to create and configure the Azure Bot Service through ARM template. I will use this in DevOps VSTS release step so that I can automate the deployment process.

Comment: Can you share you existing template?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no officially supported prebuilt ARM Templates available.
Reference [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4812). But what can be done is, deploy the resources manually from the azure portal and navigate to `resourceGroup Homepage -> Automation Script` and grab the template from there and modify it as needed.

[image: Like this]